# filtrar consulta por rango de fechas sql

Tags: c#, sql

hola buenas estoy haciendo un programa en c# y ocupaba realizar una consulta para imprimir en un combobox un rango de fechas pero pasa que las fechas yo no las se ejemplo
yo ago una reserviacion para el dia 29 osea hoy del cliente melani pero adicionalmente ago otras para el dia 30, 1 de mayo, 2 de mayo
pero en un combobox solo puedo imprimir las fechas a partir del dia 29 que es el dia de la primera afiliacion y solo puedo mostrar 2 dias adicionales osea solo deberia la fecha del 29 abril hasta 1 de mayo. pero nose como hacerlo

estaba intentando hacer una consulta asi

```
select a.FechaCupo from CupoSede a where a.FechaCupo >= GETDATE()+1 AND FechaCupo < GETDATE()+3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi se ve mi tabla con las fechas por cupos.

*se que debo hacer un inner join para relacionar al cliente con las sedes que se an relacionado a el*

pero me gustaria pedirles cualquier ayuda para ver si logro completar parte de mi consulta, como les comento las fechas yo no las se, yo lo unico que se es que deben filtrarse solo fechas comenzando del primer dia que se hizo la afiliacion ejemplo si estas tres sedes estan relacionadas a un mismo cliente  todas son del msimo dia por ente las muestro pero si uviera una que sobrepasara el maximo que son 3 dias no se muestra pero nose como hacerlo.

les agradesco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ayudarte, no entiendo bien lo que necesitas. Si lo que quieres es que te muestre el campo FechaCupo desde el día de hoy hasta 3 días más poniendo

`select FechaCupo from CupoSede where FechaCupo > GETDATE() AND FechaCupo < GETDATE()+3`

debería funcionar tal como indicaste mostrándote los registros desde la fecha de mañana hasta dos días más. Si lo que quieres es que te muestre  los registros de los dias siguientes al primer registro con fecha sería algo así:

`select FechaCupo from CupoSede where FechaCupo >= (select Top 1 FechaCupo) And FechaCupo < (select dateadd(day, 3, (select top 1 FechaCupo from CupoSede)))`

Le indico como Top 1 la primera fecha registrada y luego con la función DateAdd le indico que como parametro de number son 3 dias y como parametro de date es el primer registro con fecha. No se si es exactamente lo que necesitas pero mira la documentación oficial ya que te puede ayudar al respecto https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: muchas gracias creo que si entendiste lo que necesito muchas gracias ya casi lo pruebo, pero si eso que me dijiste es lo que necesito que se muestren 3 fechas a partir del dia pero con mi select no funcionaba, veo que el tuyo esta un poco mas pro , fijo funciona